# How to store an image without using django forms

Tags: python, django

html form:

```
<form action = "{% url 'newcomplaint' %}" class = 'newc' method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
    { % csrf_token % }

    <div class = "form-group" >
    <label for = "fileToUpload" > Add an image(optional) < /label >
    <input type = "file" name = "fileToUpload" id = "fileToUpload" >
    </div >

    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-dark bb" > Post New Complaint < /button >
</form >
```

views.py:
Here I am getting `MultiValueDictKeyError at /hood/new`

```
def newcomplaint(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # I dont know how to store a image here
        image = request.FILES['fileToupload']
        #print(image)
        return HttpResponse('works')
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Complain(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
```

All the solutions that I see are done using django forms, I want to avoid that as I have made a bigger form with image field plus some other input (and added styling and Js check for validation).

So how to retrieve a file from a form and store it in django.

Answer (score 1):

Your code expects `fileToupload` to be the key, however, your form uses `fileToUpload`.

Comment: omg! thank you so much. Also I found a  [solution](https://www.jborowski.eu/2018/06/handling-files-upload-in-django-python-3-without-forms/)

Answer (score 1):

I had a typo, also found a solution [how to store a file/image in django without forms](https://www.jborowski.eu/2018/06/handling-files-upload-in-django-python-3-without-forms/)

my working code:
views.py

```
def newcomplaint(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    newcomplaint = Complain.objects.create(
        user=request.user,
        title=request.POST['title'],
        content = request.POST['content'],
        ran = request.POST['range'],
        lati = request.POST['lati'],
        longi = request.POST['longi'],
        )

    if len(request.FILES) == 0:
        print('no files')
    else: 
        _, file = request.FILES.popitem()
        file = file[0]
        newcomplaint.image = file
        newcomplaint.save()
    


    return HttpResponse('works')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo. You have written `fileToupload`. It should be `fileToUpload`